# Python DNS module import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, resolver

I have been using python dns module.I was trying to use it on a new Linux installation but the module is not getting loaded.
I have tried to clean up and install but the installation does not seem to be working.

```
    $ python --version
    Python 2.7.3
    $ sudo pip install dnspython
    Downloading/unpacking dnspython
      Downloading dnspython-1.11.1.zip (220Kb): 220Kb downloaded
      Running setup.py egg_info for package dnspython

    Installing collected packages: dnspython
      Running setup.py install for dnspython

    Successfully installed dnspython
    Cleaning up...
    $ python
    Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
    [GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import dns
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    ImportError: No module named dns
```

Updated Output of python version and pip version command

```
    $ which python
    /usr/bin/python
    $ python --version
    Python 2.7.3
    $ pip --version
    pip 1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Note:- I have firewall installed on the new machine. I am not sure if it should effect the import. but i have tried disabling it and still it does not seem to work.

Comment: Most likely dnspython was installed for another version of Python on your system. For example, some systems have Python 2.4 installed by default.

Comment: You might try one of the two top answers to this other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2812520/42346

Comment: Thanks @bernie.
I tried the answers for the other stack-overflow but i think I don't have multiple version of python installed.

Also the pip installed to be matching the version of python.
I have edited the answer above to show the pip version and python version.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with dnspython.

My solution was to build the source from their official GitHub project.

So my steps were:

```
git clone https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython
cd dnspython/
python setup.py install
```

After doing this, I was able to import the `dns` module.

**EDIT**

It seems the pip install doesn't work for this module. Install from source as described.

Comment: Thanks @DanGar
I was able to build the package and install it now its working.
However do you know if this is happening because of the module or some trouble in the installation in my setup.

Comment: Glad it worked :) It is most likely an issue with the installation of our setup as I have had your approach work on other dev machines.

Comment: For python3 in Debian `sudo apt-get install python3-dnspython`

Answer (score 19):

I solved this by uninstalling and then re-installing the dnspython module with PIP.

```
$ pip uninstall dnspython
```

After the long list of files within pycache, type y to continue with the uninstall.  After complete type:

```
$ pip install dnspython
```

I then ran my script and the errors were resolved.

Answer (score 8):

You could also install the package with pip by using this command:

`pip install git+https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython`

Comment: This also works for the zip files, etc. example: `pip install https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/archive/v1.15.0.zip`

Answer (score 4):

I installed **dnspython 1.11.1** on my Ubuntu box using `pip install dnspython`. I was able to import the dns module without any problems

I am using Python 2.7.4 on an Ubuntu based server.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I hava writen the code in the file named "dns.py", it's conflict for the package, I have to rename the script filename.

Answer (score 3):

On Debian 7 Wheezy, I had to do:

```
pip install --upgrade dnspython
```

even if python-dns package was installed.

Answer (score 2):

Very possible the version of pip you're using isn't installing to the version of python you're using.  I have a box where this is the case...

try:

```
which python

python --version

pip -V
```

If it looks like pip doesn't match your python, then you probably have something like the multiple versions of python and pip I found on my box...

```
[root@sdpipeline student]# locate bin/pip

/home/student/class/bin/pip

/home/student/class/bin/pip-2.7

/usr/bin/pip

/usr/bin/pip-python
```

As long as I use /home/student/class/bin/pip (2.7 that matches my python version on that box), then my imports work fine.

You can also try installing pip from source: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html

There's probably a better way to do this, I'm still learning my way around too, but that's how I solved it -- hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @scottsanchez 
I have updated the post above to show the output of pip version and python version.
But it seems I only have one installation of python.
I will try installing pip from source and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason here might be your script have wrong **shebang** (so it is not using python from your virtualenv). I just did this change and it works:

```
-#!/bin/python
+#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Or ignore shebang and just run the script with python in your venv:

```
$ python your_script.py
```

Comment: this was the case for me where where cli python was `/usr/local/bin/python` but shebang was `#!/usr/bin/python3`

Answer (score 1):

I was getting an error while using "import dns.resolver". I tried dnspython, py3dns but they failed.
dns won't install. after much hit and try I installed pubdns module and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and solved this like i described below:
As You have downloaded and installed dnspython successfully so

1. Enter into folder dnspython
2. You will find dns directory, now copy it
3. Then paste it to inside site-packages directory

That's all. Now your problem will go

If dnspython isn't installed you can install it this way :

1. go to your python installation folder site-packages directory
2. open cmd here and enter the command : 
   `pip install dnspython`

Now, dnspython will be installed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing has happened to me and it turns out that the .py file had the name dns (dns.py) and apparently it cannot have that name since it is the name of the package and it is a problem, so I recommend trying to change the name for example (dns_1.py) in case dns is named

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be generated by Symantec End Point Protection (SEP).
And I suspect most EPP products could potentially impact your running of scripts.

If SEP is disabled, the script will run instantly.

Therefore you may need to update the SEP policy to not block python scripts accessing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I installed DNSpython 2.0.0 from the github source, but running 'pip list' showed the old version of dnspython 1.2.0

It only worked after I ran 'pip uninstall dnspython' which removed the old version leaving just 2.0.0 and then 'import dns' ran smoothly

Answer (score 0):

ok to  resolve this First install dns for python by cmd using  `pip install dnspython`
(if you use conda first type `activate` and then you will go in base (in cmd) and then type above code) 
it will install it in anaconda site package ,copy the location of that site package folder from cmd, and open it . Now copy all dns folders and paste them in python site package folder. it will resolve it .

actually the thing is our code is not able to find the specified package in python\site package bcz it is in anaconda\site package. so you have to COPY IT (not cut).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue when importing on mac.i have python 3.7.3 installed
Following steps helped me resolve it:

1. pip3 uninstall dnspython
2. sudo -H pip3 install dnspython

Import dns

Import dns.resolver

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have (or don't want) `pip` installed there is another way. You can to solve this is to install package with native OS package manager.

For example for Debian-based systems this would be command:

`apt install python3-dnspython`