# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnspython'

Tags: python, python-3.6, dnspython

I am trying to import the module `dnspython` in a python 3.6 script using `import dnspython`.

`pip3 freeze` shows that the package is installed but I keep getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnspython'`

I have tried:

- `pip3 install dnspython`
- uninstalling and reinstalling with pip3
- `pip3 install git+https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython`
- Cloning the package from github and installing with `sudo python setup.py install`
- `pip3 install dnspython3` and using `import dnspython3` in the script
- Copying the dns folder of the cloned package in the site-packages folder

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641696/python-dns-module-import-error) post for python 2.7 but none of the solutions worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was `import dnspython`. Changing it into `import dns` worked fine.

Some test code:

```
import dns

result = dns.resolver.query('google.com', 'A')
for ipval in result:
    print('IP', ipval.to_text())

# Output: IP {your ip}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me (Python 3.8.5):

```
pip install dnspython3
```

code:

```
import dns
from dns import resolver 

result = resolver.resolve('google.com')
for ipval in result:
    print('IP', ipval.to_text())
```