# Visual Studio Code not recognizing Python Azure Function local library import

Tags: python, azure-functions

I'm just starting with Azure Functions using Python. My library import of dnspython is not being recognized properly in Visual Studio Code.

I have Visual Studio Code v1.74 and am writing an Azure Function in Python. I did a PIP IMPORT of the Python library DNSPYTHON and verified that it is in my local environment via pip -list in the Terminal window of Visual Studio Code. However, the import Intellisense throws an error saying "Import "dnspython" could not be resolved." Screenshot below

**Import DNSPYTHON throws pylance error, but PIP LIST shows it in the local environment**

[image]
Any suggestions of what I could try to resolve this? I'm wondering if there is some sort of PATH problem perhaps.

EDIT: I'm using v2 of the programming model

Answer (score 0):

> Import "dnspython" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)

I have created the Python v2 model Azure Functions - Http Trigger using VS Code and written the sample code for using the package `dns`.

```
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  logging
import  dns
import  dns.resolver

app = func.FunctionApp()
@app.function_name(name="HttpTrigger1")
@app.route(route="hello")
def  test_function(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

#example code for import dns
result = dns.resolver.query('google.com', 'A')
for  ipval  in  result:
    print('IP', ipval.to_text())

#example code for import dns.resolver
answers = dns.resolver.resolve('dnspython.org', 'MX')
for  rdata  in  answers:
    print('Host', rdata.exchange, 'has preference', rdata.preference)

return  func.HttpResponse(f"Hello Krishna, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.", status_code=200)
```

[image]

The packages `dns` and `dns.resolver` are working successfully in Python Azure Functions v2 model.
To solve the import error issue, follow the below steps:

1. Activate the Virtual Environment in the Project Terminal of VS Code.
2. Then install the required packages using `pip` command.
3. In requirements.txt file, mention the packages used in the function code file such as:

```
azure-functions
dns
dns.resovler
```

Note: *Above parts of the code taken from references [dnspython](https://www.dnspython.org/examples/) examples site and Charalamm's [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61150609)*.