# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQL' how do I solve this?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I installed MySQL connector Python 8.0.11 using `pip3` and it was installed successfully. I am running this on my macOS. And whenever I try `import mysql.connector` there is a trace back error "`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'`". How can I solve this?

Comment: what python you are using anaconda or python3.x? just check where the packages stored after the installation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'MySQL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877671/importerror-no-module-named-mysql)

Comment: @kkheelan now the trace back error says that no module named dns.resolver. I searched the directory and i have download mysql-connector-python-rf too. what could i do?

Comment: @Nikesh shah you can try to install dnspython using pip. But if it doesn't work, sometimes pip doesn't work for some modules then you have to follow the answer of this link to install dns. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641696/python-dns-module-import-error